# show UI Porgress which do some process in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

please tell me what is the technique or some code how could i show user when downloading some thing and i want to show the user alert and the downloading percentage too in iPhone, but the code is simple not too much complicated or some public library is available for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to perform this task. To implement this you'll need to implement the NSURLConnection delegate Methods.

In your m you'll need to implement a few delegate class methods

```
//NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [progressView setProgress:receivedData.length/contentLength];
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    [progressView setProgress:0];
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    if (receivedData.length > 0) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"WriteZip");
        [receivedData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file.zip",documentsDirectory] atomically:YES];

     [self finishedUpdating];
    [theConnection release];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    [self finishedUpdating];
}
```

Here is an example of what my H looks like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UpdateViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
    NSURLConnection *theConnection;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    float contentLength;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *progressContainer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel;
-(void)requestUpdates;
-(void)finishedUpdating;
@end
```

Some Docs to read

[NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[URL System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

Comment: hello mobileOverload thanks for the great code again you are very good dev. now i have 1 query can i implement those class in the previuos then while downloading the image they will also show the progress too.. if you don't understand then let me know..

Comment: The progress is being set in the various parts of the connection. In didRecieveData `[progressView setProgress:receivedData.length/contentLength];` will set the progress of the progress bar everytime is gets more data. If you are having trouble with the progress displaying properly then you may want to make sure that the server is setting the content length header properly. Otherwise, if the app doesn't know what the content length is supposed to be, it can't make a progress bar. You should use UIActivityView for that.

Answer (score 1):

using [asi-http-request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) with any hud library like [ATMHud](https://github.com/atomton/ATMHud)

```
//Create the hud
self.hud = [[[ATMHud alloc] initWithDelegate:nil] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:hud.view];

[hud setCaption:@"Just a caption..."];
[hud setProgress:0.04];
[hud show];

//Create the request
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Make the request to update the hud
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self.hud];
request.showAccurateProgress = YES;


[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    //get your response here
    [request responseData];
    [request responseString];
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```